# Mysql RENAME always returns false with mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, return-value

Here is a pretty simple code :

```
$query = "RENAME TABLE myOldTableName TO myNewTableName";
$is_ok = mysql_query($query);
echo ($is_ok) ? "Rename OK" : "Rename aborted";
```

But it alwayls print "Rename aborted".

I found on [php.net](http://goo.gl/S4jFq) :

```
When processing a RENAME TABLE query, PHP apparently always returns false, 
no matter if the query was successfully processed or not.
```

I tried `mysql_affected_rows`, but not working..
Any idea to know if the rename worked or not ? (without another query like `SELECT`, or `SHOW TABLES`, etc).

Thanks !

Comment: I'm confused as below below link says that it will return **TRUE**

http://ruleant.blogspot.com/2009/03/rename-multiple-tables-in-mysql.html

Comment: @FahimParkar Wow, interesting, I will do tests one more time.

Comment: Guys ! I did some mistakes : Indeed, in my last test, I've used `&& mysql_affected_rows()` in my if. I don't reach to reproduce the first test which always return me false. At the moment, mysql_query returns me true if the rename succeed and false if not. That's all I wanted ! mysql_affected_rows() returns me int(0) if rename succeed, and int(-1) if not. At the present time, I'm carrying on reproduce the problem. I 'll let you know.

Comment: Ash, answer your own question at the bottom, and then close it using that :)

Comment: Well, yesterday I wanted to do that but I couldn't 'cause I have < 100rep, so I had to wait few hours. But Now I can (btw I can accept it only tomorow) ;) Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after many tests, here we are :

```
RENAME TABLE `mytable_a` TO `mytable_b`
mysql_query           :  bool(true)
mysql_affected_rows() :  int(0)
mysql_info()          :  bool(false)

RENAME TABLE `tableNotExists` TO `FooBar`
mysql_query           :  bool(false)
mysql_affected_rows() :  int(-1)
mysql_info()          :  bool(false)

ALTER TABLE `mytable_b` CHANGE `fieldFOO` `fieldBAR` INT(11) NOT NULL
mysql_query           :  bool(true)
mysql_affected_rows() :  int(42053)
mysql_info()          :  string(42) "Records: 42053 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0"

ALTER TABLE `mytable_b` CHANGE `fieldNotExists` `newName` INT(11) NOT NULL
mysql_query           :  bool(false)
mysql_affected_rows() :  int(-1)
mysql_info()          :  bool(false)
```

After all, RENAME TABLE seems to work fine. The comment on php.net is apparently wrong, and I went as wrong as him on my first tests.

I want to thank **Fahim Parkar** who put his finger on a solution, and **Entropy** and **Leigh** who offer me alternative ;)

Tell me if something seems wrong !

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `RENAME TABLE` in a stored procedure that does something like `SELECT 1 AS STATUS` on success

Comment: For internally needs, I can't use stored procedure, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Ask to the `information_schema` table:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = '$youDatabaseName' 
AND table_name = '$myNewTableName'");
```

Or if you don't like `information_schema`:

```
mysql_query("DESCRIBE $myNewTableName");
```

which return `false` for a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: I thought about that but I don't want to use the `information_schema` table, for purist reasons ;) Indeed, I'm not sure that table is up to date because of others devloppers's activities.

Comment: That table is automatically updated by MySQL, unless they manually edit it, it's always up to date ;) I edited my answer with an alternative.

Comment: As I self-answered me, all's well that ends well, and yes, your alternative works fine !